# Hiding date in formula if nothing is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to have a Date forumla that adds 7 days to a date entered in another cell, but if nothing is entered I would like said cell to be blank

A1 if blank then have B1 blank
A1 is 2/1/2015 then have B1 as 2/8/2015

Answer (score 3):

Format **B1** as *Date*  *mm/dd/yyyy* and then in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1+7)
```